# search multiple keywords with wp_query using one query

Tags: wp-query

I use this wp_query to get results for a specific keyword and sort by price. I need to search multiple keywords at the same time and return results and sort them by product price. How is this possible using one wp_query? Any example appreciated.

```
 $args = array(

        's' => "t",
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    'sentence' => true,
        'paged'=>$paged,
        'meta_query' => [

            'product_price'  => [ 'key' => 'product_price', 'value' => '0', 'compare' => '>' , 'type'=>'NUMERIC'],


    ],

    'orderby' => 'product_price',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    );
```

Comment: You can use comma or space to search multiple keywords - e.g. `one, two` (OR query) or `one two` (AND query). But the `sentence` param should be set to `false`.

Comment: Hmmm but i want to search using a phrase...because my keywords are like this “i want this” , “i want that” . Its not a continues word like iwantthis or iwantthat. The words i need to search have spaces.

Comment: So for example, you want to search for posts where the title or content contains `i want this` *or* `i want that`?

Comment: Yes exactly...i dont know how to write correctly the ‘s’ parameter ...

Comment: You can use quotes - `"i want this", "i want that"` - but that will search for posts where for example the title *contains both* the keywords. If you want to search for posts where the title matches *any* of the keywords, then you need to write custom SQL queries for that. And you can use hooks like `posts_where`.